# How to open PowerShell in the current Explorer window by typing ps in the address bar?

Tags: windows, powershell

I know I can type "cmd" in the Windows Explorer address bar and it works with "Powershell". Is it possible to set an alias such that I can type just "ps"?

Comment: Does this help? https://adamtheautomator.com/windows-open-powershell-in-a-folder/

Comment: ***Aliasing is not a thing in WE that I am aware of or have ever seen.*** Why try and use WE and a *.exe launcher; when WInKey+Rallows you to do that? Just put it on the taskbar and use the WinKey+NumberPosition to launch it. Note, that hotkey is only for 1-9 and 0. After that, you'd assign a hotkey.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I must say: Woah.

Comment: LOL :-D If it works, please do feel free to write an answer. Step-by-step instructions would come handy... I know I'm going to need that info when next time I need to use Windows :-)

Comment: @Peregrino69 Appreciate it, see answer below

Comment: Nice and concise :-) Please don't forget to check back in 48 hours to accept the answer so it gets marked as resolved. That'll make it useful in the future for others... including myself :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the info contained at the destination of the link posted by @Peregrino69 the lowest-friction, least-hand movement needing solution to me is

1. Open the Windows Explorer window where PowerShell should open
2. Press ALT (not ALT-GR)
3. Press F
4. Press R (optionally to open PowerShell as administrator, press S followed by A)

Answer (score 0):

1. focus address bar of the folder: "Ctrl + L"
2. type "pwsh"